# How to clear interval in recursive call in javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am using `setInterval();` function to run a function every 5 sec, but i want to clear this interval if
some condition satisfied.

```
function do_the_job(){ 
 //some code
 if(some_condition)
  {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }else{
      clearInterval(interval);
      var interval = setInterval(do_the_job(),5000);
      }
 }
```

function `clearInterval();` is not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the `var interval =...` is local, not visible outside the scope of the function call, and thus will not work in a recursive function.

Make the `interval` a global variable, and it will work.

**solution**

```
var interval;
function do_the_job(){ 
 //some code
 if(some_condition)
  {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }else{
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = setInterval(do_the_job(),5000);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `interval` a global or 'higher scoped' variable by moving its declaration outside the `if` statements, so that it's actually in scope when clearing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good time to use `setInterval()`, try `setTimeout()` instead

```
function do_the_job(){ 
 //some code
 if(some_condition)
  {
     // job done
  }else{
      setTimeout(do_the_job,5000);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var interval = setInterval(do_the_job(),5000);
```

Should be no parethesees

```
 var interval = setInterval(do_the_job,5000);
```